# format R output to get each result in separate line and with alphabet as line identifiers

Tags: r, formatting, output, line

When I try to get unique values, following is the result I got.

```
unique( big1.csv[grepl("c1", tolower(big1.csv$Remarks)) &grepl("arm", tolower(big1.csv$Remarks))
                           &grepl("back", tolower(big1.csv$Remarks))
                           , ]$New_Remarks)

[1] "c1 noted to back and arms, dose repeated"               "c1 noted to back of arms and flanks, dose repeated"    
 [3] "c1 noted to arms and back, dose repeated"               "c1 noted to back and upper arms, dose repeated"        
 [5] "c1 noted to back of arms, dose repeated"                "c1 noted to back and chest, dose repeated"
```

How can I get each result in a separate line with alphabets instead of line numbers  like this? Or roman numbers?

```
 [a] "c1 noted to back and arms, dose repeated" 
 [b] "c1 noted to back of arms and flanks, dose repeated"    
 [c] "c1 noted to arms and back, dose repeated"   
 [d] "c1 noted to back and upper arms, dose repeated"        
 [e] "c1 noted to back of arms, dose repeated" 
 [f] "c1 noted to back and chest, dose repeated"
```

Comment: You can try saving the result to data.frame or data.table, adding ID column with whatever you want (try `LETTERS`), then exporting as a CSV.

Comment: hi M.D, I saved that unique line to variable b and used the following code, b= as.data.frame(ID=LETTERS,b ). It did give me the results in seperate lines, but I got line numbers without " [ " & " ] " instead of letters. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you could combine your `unique.strings` with a custom made `ID` in a data frame.

```
unique.strings <- unique( big1.csv[grepl("e1", tolower(big1.csv$Remarks)) &grepl("arm", tolower(big1.csv$Remarks))
                       &grepl("back", tolower(big1.csv$Remarks))
                       , ]$New_Remarks)
df <- data.frame(ID = paste0("[", letters[1:length(unique.strings)], "]"), unique.strings)
```

Comment: thanks zyurnaidi I used df <- data.frame(ID = paste0("[", letters[1:dim(unique.strings)[1]], "]"), unique.strings)

Comment: yes. that would've been better. I edit the code using slightly different function of `length`, since I assume the `unique.strings` is a character vector

Answer (score 2):

I think you need rownames, see this example:

```
unique.strings <- c("xxx", "yyy", "zzz")

df <- data.frame(unique.strings)
rownames(df) <- make.unique(letters[1:nrow(df)])

df
#   unique.strings
# a            xxx
# b            yyy
# c            zzz
```